# How to load CSV files data from S3 to MySQL RDS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

So I have been trying to create a Lambda function that is triggered with an event from my S3 bucket every time a csv file is uploaded (this csv file contains new questions/choices/answer for my RDSmySQL Database already created). I want the lambda function to take that csv and update the DB with the new questions.

I started creating this in my VScode and looks like that at the moment

** for the rds settings i know this is not best practice for security purposes
**but if there is a better way please let me know i would appreciate that very much

```
import sys
import boto3
import logging
import pymysql
import json
import csv
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# rds settings
rds_host  = "database.amazonaws.com(example)"
user_name = "admin(example)"
password = "admin(example)"
db_name = "admin(example)"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create the database connection outside of the handler to allow connections to be
# re-used by subsequent function invocations.
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, user=user_name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Get the S3 bucket and key from the event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    csv_file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    csv_file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=csv_file)
    lines = csv_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()

    results = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
         results.append(tuple(row.values()))

    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        for row in results:
            # Insert new question into the database
            sql = "INSERT INTO questions (Question_ID, Question_TEXT, Choice_A, Choice_B, Choice_C, Choice_D, Correct_Answer) VALUES ("+ row[0] + "," + row[1] + "," + row[2] + "," + row[3] + "," + row[4] + "," + row[5] + ","+ row[6] +")"
            cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()

    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT * from questions"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        query_results = cursor.fetchall()
        print(query_results)

    return "Added %d items to RDS MySQL table"
```

Now when I inputted this in my newly created Lambda function, I went ahead and made a layer for all the packages used in a zip file and ran a test but i came across an error:

```
testFUNction

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymysql'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "(EXAMPLE)",
  "stackTrace": []
}
Function Logs
START RequestId: (EXAMPLE) Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymysql'
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: (EXAMPLE)
REPORT RequestId: (EXAMPLE) Duration: 1.36 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 53 MB
```

The following picture is what's inside the layer i created for Lambda function:

[ZipFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftf4Q.png)

I have looked around for a couple days reading different documentations and forums but i haven't been able to figure this out. Can anyone help me solve this issue?